# Soft Key board not coming

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an edit text, which based on some condition, i dynamically want to perform click, so i use :0 `editText.performClick()`

Using this the click event is triggered and also i can see the focus in the edit text, but soft keyboard is not coming up, I also tried :-

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(editText,
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(editText,
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

But the key board is not coming up.... Any ideas..... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try InputMethodManager's toggleSoftInput method.